# return redirect()->action('BookingController@index') laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am following a tutorial using old version of laravel , but I am using Laravel 8
this line of code is causing error :

```
return redirect()->action('BookingController@index');
```

it is in the store action in BookingController.php ,
This is the output of the error

```
Action BookingController@index not defined.
```

do anyone has an idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can try `redirect()->action('App\Http\Controllers\BookingController@index');`

Comment: Thanks @Espresso , it works , could you please make it as an answer not comment in order to submit it as the correct answer

Comment: Now actually it has been changed in Laravel 8. `return redirect()->action([HomeController::class, 'index']);` check doc https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/redirects#redirecting-controller-actions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In previous releases of **Laravel 8**, the `RouteServiceProvider` class contained a `$namespace` property with a value of `App\Http\Controllers`. The value of this property was used to automatically prefix controller route declarations and controller route URL generation such as when calling the `action` helper :

```
redirect()->action('App\Http\Controllers\BookingController@index');
```

See [Upgrade Guide to Laravel 8.x (Automatic Controller Namespace Prefixing)](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade)